# Use of undeclared type 'BackendlessCollection'

Tags: swift, backendless

Hi I am new to Backendless. Please help. I am getting an error like Use of undeclared type 'BackendlessCollection' while using it in a ios . swift

I have written  function retrieveBlurbs() in home view controller.I have created one more object medicineList class like this

```
class medicineList : NSObject
{

    var objectId : String?
    var name : String?

    var desc : String?
    var created : NSDate?
    var updated : NSDate?

}


func retrieveBlurbs()
{
    var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
    let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
    // Use backendless.persistenceService to obtain a ref to a data store for the class
    backendless.persistenceService.ofTable(medicineList.ofClass()).find(query, response: { ( medicineList : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
        let currentPage = medicineList.getCurrentPage()
        print("Loaded \(currentPage.count) medicineList objects")
        print("Total restaurants in the Backendless starage - \(medicineList.totalObjects)")

        for medicineList in currentPage as! [medicineList]
        {
            print("Medicine name = \(medicineList.name)")
        }




    } , error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC3vu.png)I'm not sure, that it will be helpful

I've looked at the API, so if you are using asynchronous method signatures, the method "find" with query variable has two non optional blocks for a response and for an error.

I would try to change that method like this:

```
func retrieveBlurbs()
{
    var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
    let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
    // Use backendless.persistenceService to obtain a ref to a data store for the class
    backendless.persistenceService.ofTable(medicineList.ofClass()).find(query) { medicineList in
        let currentPage = medicineList.getCurrentPage()
        print("Loaded \(currentPage.count) medicineList objects")
        print("Total restaurants in the Backendless starage - \(medicineList.totalObjects)")

        for medicineList in currentPage as! [medicineList]
        {
            print("Medicine name = \(medicineList.name)")
        }

    } , { fault in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
        }
}
```

If this won't help, then maybe you have to make an sdk setup from the very beginning, some module or file might was missing during the first setup

Comment: I edited woof answer...but still getting an error like 'cannot convert value of type Anyclass! to expected argument type string !' error in line PersistanceService line of code

Comment: backendless connection i did correctly at the begining

Comment: can you send me one example code to retrieve list of all the name from backendless table .. I need to display that table list in a table view controller..

Comment: I haven't implemented that sdk in my project. But it seems that now the error is different. Where exactly this error is marked? I mean what object or variable is trying to use that string value?

Comment: Is it possible for you to send your project or share a link in github or whatever? I will play with it